# How to avoid xmlns="" to be added to a manipulated XML root element?

Tags: java, xml

I'm changing the `jta-data-source` value of a `persistence.xml` as follows:

```
JavaArchive jarArchive = Maven.configureResolver().workOffline().resolve("richtercloud:project1-jar:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT").withoutTransitivity().asSingle(JavaArchive.class);
Node persistenceXml = jarArchive.get("META-INF/persistence.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document persistenceXmlDocument = documentBuilder.parse(persistenceXml.getAsset().openStream());
    //asked
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46771622/how-to-create-a-shrinkwrap-persistencedescriptor-from-an-existing-persistence-xm
    //for how to manipulate persistence.xml more easily with
    //ShrinkWrap's PersistenceDescriptor
XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//persistence-unit/jta-data-source");
org.w3c.dom.Node persistenceXmlDataSourceNode = (org.w3c.dom.Node) expr.evaluate(persistenceXmlDocument,
        XPathConstants.NODE);
persistenceXmlDataSourceNode.setTextContent("jdbc/project1-test-db");

TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
//transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
//was there before, but unclear why
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(persistenceXmlDocument), new StreamResult(writer));
String persistenceUnit = writer.toString();
```

(since [How to create a ShrinkWrap PersistenceDescriptor from an existing persistence.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46771622/how-to-create-a-shrinkwrap-persistencedescriptor-from-an-existing-persistence-xm) has not been answered, yet).

That works fine, except for a `xmlns=""` attribute added to the `persistence-unit` under the root `persistence` element which seems to cause:

> java.io.IOException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 108; Deployment descriptor file META-INF/persistence.xml in archive [project1-jar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar].  cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'persistence-unit'. One of '{"http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence":persistence-unit}' is expected.

I'm not adhering to the idea to use Transformer and related classes.

Comment: Could you please post the input file to be able to see and reproduce the problem?

Comment: @SergeyBrunov I just realized that this only happens in the `@Deployment` method of an Arquillian Drone test method and is not reproducible in a Java SE program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea why I can't reproduce this in Java SE, but the problem is that `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder` by default isn't namespace aware so that the namespace information gets lost during manipulation of the document and consequently an empty `xmlns` is added by `Transformer`.

Now that `DocumentBuilder` is namespace aware, XPath resolution doesn't work and queries return `null`, see [XPath returning null for "Node" when isNameSpaceAware and isValidating are "true"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760343/xpath-returning-null-for-node-when-isnamespaceaware-and-isvalidating-are-true) for a detailed description and more details on the XPath namespace awareness issue (I couldn't get the solution to build a custom NamespaceContext to work).

In order to avoid this I finally adjusted my XPath query to use the `local-name` function as described at [How to ignore namespace when selecting XML nodes with XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402310/how-to-ignore-namespace-when-selecting-xml-nodes-with-xpath). i.e. `//*[local-name()='jta-data-source']`.

It's still necessary to use `Document.createElementNS` instead of `createElement` in order to avoid empty `xmlns` attribute on newly created elements, see [Empty default XML namespace xmlns="" attribute being added?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323227/empty-default-xml-namespace-xmlns-attribute-being-added) for an explanation.