# “IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory” in arquillian

Tags: java, maven, jsf, jakarta-ee, jboss-arquillian

[`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory.` is caused by the presence of a JSF API inside a dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46680947/illegalstateexception-could-not-find-backup-for-factory-javax-faces-context-fa). I'm eager to provide dependencies in the WAR or EAR of my Java EE applications instead of using the dependency artifacts provided by the server because that increases flexibility when it comes to necessary updates (assuming that updating the server artifacts) in my experience. That makes it easy to compare a deployment on Payara 4.1.2.181 to one to the embedded version done by Arquillian. I control the classloading with `<class-loader delegate="false"/>` added to `/WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml`.

Unfortunately, the error message is not helpful and afaik one has to go through the Maven dependencies and test exclusions in a trial-error approach. There're some "usual suspects" which are worth trying which I collected from different posts: `jsf-impl.jar`, `javax.faces.jar`, `jsf-api.jar`, `javaee.jar`.

Given a fairly simple JSF project with 1 backing bean producing `"Hello world!"` for a `h:outputLabel` the deployment works on Payara, but not with Arquillian with the functional test

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
@RunAsClient
public class FunctionalIT {
    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FunctionalIT.class);

    @Deployment(testable = false)
    public static Archive<?> createDeployment0() throws TransformerException, XPathExpressionException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        WebArchive retValue = Maven.configureResolver().workOffline().resolve("richtercloud:arquillian-assertt-statements-web:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT")
                .withoutTransitivity().asSingle(WebArchive.class);
        ByteArrayOutputStream archiveContentOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        retValue.writeTo(archiveContentOutputStream, Formatters.VERBOSE);
        LOGGER.info(archiveContentOutputStream.toString());
        return retValue;
    }

    @Drone
    private WebDriver browser;
    @ArquillianResource
    private URL deploymentUrl;
    @FindBy(id = "helloWorldLabel")
    private WebElement helloWorldLabel;

    @Test
    public void testAll() {
        browser.get(deploymentUrl.toExternalForm()+"/index.xhtml");
        LOGGER.info(browser.getPageSource());
        new WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(helloWorldLabel));
    }
}
```

since the Arquillian deployment fails due to (the functional test is run with the `maven-failsafe-plugin`)

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory. 
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:541)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:292)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1435)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5468)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5713)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:609)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:900)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:684)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2057)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1703)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:294)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:357)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.initialize(ApplicationLifecycle.java:526)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:510)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:549)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:545)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:544)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:575)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:567)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:566)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1474)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:111)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1856)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1732)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.DeployerImpl.deploy(DeployerImpl.java:134)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.DeployerImpl.deploy(DeployerImpl.java:110)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.glassfish.embedded_3_1.GlassFishContainer.deploy(GlassFishContainer.java:193)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:151)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:118)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.executeOperation(ContainerDeployController.java:239)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.deploy(ContainerDeployController.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.DeploymentExceptionHandler.verifyExpectedExceptionDuringDeploy(DeploymentExceptionHandler.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createDeploymentContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:133)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:105)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:62)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$1.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:92)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$1.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:77)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:232)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachManagedDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:212)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.deployManaged(ContainerDeployController.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:133)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:105)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:62)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:133)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:105)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeClass(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:179)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:384)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:54)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:369)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:275)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:239)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:373)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:334)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:119)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:407)
```

Now, I don't seem to be able to apply the solution provided in the link above since there seems to be no dependency matching or similar to the ones listed above:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] arquillian-assertt-statements
[INFO] arquillian-assertt-statements-web
[INFO] arquillian-assertt-statements-it
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building arquillian-assertt-statements 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ arquillian-assertt-statements ---
[INFO] richtercloud:arquillian-assertt-statements:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building arquillian-assertt-statements-web 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ arquillian-assertt-statements-web ---
[INFO] richtercloud:arquillian-assertt-statements-web:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.primefaces:primefaces:jar:6.1:compile
[INFO] \- javax:javaee-web-api:jar:7.0:provided
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building arquillian-assertt-statements-it 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ arquillian-assertt-statements-it ---
[INFO] richtercloud:arquillian-assertt-statements-it:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-javaee:jar:2.0.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-container:jar:1.2.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.test:arquillian-test-api:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.core:arquillian-core-api:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.test:arquillian-test-spi:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.core:arquillian-core-spi:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-api:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-api:jar:1.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-spi:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.core:arquillian-core-impl-base:jar:1.2.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.test:arquillian-test-impl-base:jar:1.2.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-impl-base:jar:1.2.0.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.config:arquillian-config-api:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.config:arquillian-config-impl-base:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-impl-base:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-impl-base:jar:1.2.6:test
[INFO] |     \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-spi:jar:1.2.6:test
[INFO] +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-depchain:pom:2.2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-api:jar:2.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-spi:jar:2.2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-spi-maven:jar:2.2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-api-maven-archive:jar:2.2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven:jar:2.2.6:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.aether:aether-api:jar:1.0.0.v20140518:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.aether:aether-impl:jar:1.0.0.v20140518:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.aether:aether-spi:jar:1.0.0.v20140518:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.aether:aether-util:jar:1.0.0.v20140518:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.aether:aether-connector-basic:jar:1.0.0.v20140518:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.aether:aether-transport-wagon:jar:1.0.0.v20140518:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-aether-provider:jar:3.2.5:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.2.5:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:jar:3.2.5:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:3.2.5:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:3.2.5:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings-builder:jar:3.2.5:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.21:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.20:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-file:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http-lightweight:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http-shared:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven-archive:jar:2.2.6:test
[INFO] |     +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-spi-maven-archive:jar:2.2.6:test
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.plexus:jar:0.3.0.M1:test
[INFO] |     |  \- org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.inject:jar:0.3.0.M1:test
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-javac:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |        \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-api:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] +- org.jboss.arquillian.graphene:graphene-webdriver:pom:2.3.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.graphene:graphene-webdriver-api:jar:2.3.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.graphene:graphene-webdriver-spi:jar:2.3.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.graphene:graphene-webdriver-impl:jar:2.3.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.extension:arquillian-drone-impl:jar:2.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.extension:arquillian-drone-configuration:jar:2.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:3.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.extension:arquillian-drone-webdriver-depchain:pom:2.5.0:test
[INFO] |     +- org.jboss.arquillian.extension:arquillian-drone-spi:jar:2.5.0:test
[INFO] |     \- org.jboss.arquillian.extension:arquillian-drone-webdriver:jar:2.5.0:test
[INFO] |        +- org.arquillian.spacelift:arquillian-spacelift:jar:1.0.2:test
[INFO] |        |  \- org.arquillian.spacelift:arquillian-spacelift-api:jar:1.0.2:test
[INFO] |        +- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.8.3:test
[INFO] |        \- org.awaitility:awaitility:jar:3.0.0:test
[INFO] |           \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:jar:3.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:jar:3.9.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:htmlunit-driver:jar:2.28:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:jar:3.9.1:compile
[INFO] +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.24:compile
[INFO] |  +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-core-js:jar:2.23:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:neko-htmlunit:jar:2.24:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.cssparser:cssparser:jar:0.9.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.w3c.css:sac:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:jar:9.2.20.v20161216:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.2.20.v20161216:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.2.20.v20161216:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:jar:9.2.20.v20161216:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:jar:9.2.20.v20161216:compile
[INFO] +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:3.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:jar:3.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-edge-driver:jar:3.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-ie-driver:jar:3.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-opera-driver:jar:3.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-safari-driver:jar:3.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:23.6-jre:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:jar:3.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.13.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:jar:3.9.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- richtercloud:selenium-tools:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- ru.yandex.qatools.ashot:ashot:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.googlecode.lambdaj:lambdaj:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-api-maven:jar:2.2.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.arquillian.extension:arquillian-drone-api:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-core:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-spi:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.protocol:arquillian-protocol-servlet:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher:arquillian-testenricher-cdi:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher:arquillian-testenricher-ejb:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher:arquillian-testenricher-resource:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher:arquillian-testenricher-initialcontext:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] \- fish.payara.extras:payara-embedded-all:jar:5.0.0.Alpha3:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] arquillian-assertt-statements ...................... SUCCESS [  0.864 s]
[INFO] arquillian-assertt-statements-web .................. SUCCESS [  0.060 s]
[INFO] arquillian-assertt-statements-it ................... SUCCESS [  0.904 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.254 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-05T11:24:55+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/303M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The same error occurs when the test is run with `maven-surefire-plugin` 2.21.0. The issue also happens with embedded Payara 5.182 and 4.1.2.181 which are the latest of the 5.x and 4.x branches.

An SSCCE which doesn't contain more information than the MCVE above, but facilitates experiments in a clone, can be found at https://gitlab.com/krichter/arquillian-assertt-statements and example output of a complete run at https://gitlab.com/krichter/arquillian-assertt-statements/-/jobs/75705830.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be fixed by adding

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

to the `web-app` section of `web.xml`. Since you might not want to pollute your production `web.xml` you can use the following to insert the `listener` programmatically (in the Arquillian `@Deployment` method for example):

```
@Deployment(testable = false)
public static Archive<?> createDeployment0() throws ParserConfigurationException,
        SAXException,
        IOException,
        XPathExpressionException,
        TransformerConfigurationException,
        TransformerException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        //namespace awareness is necessary in order to avoid an empty
        //`xmlns` attribute to be added to the persistence-unit element in
        //the output which causes failure of the functional test due to
        //`java.io.IOException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 108; Deployment descriptor file META-INF/persistence.xml in archive [project1-jar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar].  cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'persistence-unit'. One of '{"http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence":persistence-unit}' is expected.`
        //see
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48362284/how-to-avoid-xmlns-to-be-added-to-a-manipulated-xml-root-element
        //for details and an explanation
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document webXmlDocument = documentBuilder.parse(new File("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml"));
    XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xPath = xPathfactory.newXPath();

    XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile("//*[local-name()='web-app']");
    Node webAppNode = (Node) expr.evaluate(webXmlDocument,
            XPathConstants.NODE);
    Element listenerNode = webXmlDocument.createElementNS(webAppNode.getNamespaceURI(),
            "listener");
        //use `createElementNS` instead of `createElement` in order to avoid
        //empty `xmlns` attribute on the created `listener` element which
        //is otherwise added even if the document builder is namespace aware
    Element listenerClassNode = webXmlDocument.createElementNS(webAppNode.getNamespaceURI(),
            "listener-class");
    listenerClassNode.setTextContent("com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener");
    listenerNode.appendChild(listenerClassNode);
    webAppNode.appendChild(listenerNode);

    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(webXmlDocument), new StreamResult(writer));
    String webXml = writer.toString();
    StringAsset webXmlAsset = new StringAsset(webXml);
    WebArchive archive = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
            .setWebXML(webXmlAsset)
            ...;
    return archive;
}
```

Use `org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.Node webXml = mavenArtifact.get("/WEB-INF/web.xml")` and parse `webXml.getAsset().openStream()` with `DocumentBuilder` to retrieve the `web.xml` if you use the complete WAR archive  in a separate project for the functional tests like in the example above.

I found the solution in [Payara bug report 1105](https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/1105) where I linked the information provided here which hopefully triggers further investigation and a fix by the Payara devs.

I added the fix on the `fix` branch of the SSCCE.